# ComboBox max records reached

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, odbc

I have a table in MySQL accessed through a linked table (via ODBC) in Microsoft Access 2013.

This table contains over 124,000 records and I need a ComboBox in a form to be able to search through the UPC column.

This is the query that is the current datasource for the ComboBox:

```
SELECT [ID], [UPC_Case], [Description] FROM itemlist ORDER BY [UPC_Case];
```

This works perfectly except that the table view under the ComboBox won't go past record number 62287 (however the auto-fill still works for records that the table can't see), is there a way to make it able to view all the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access ComboBoxes have a maximum record count of 65535.

To circumvent this, I found [an article](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-32.html) that gave me the groundwork required to write a function that sets the rowSource dynamically once a certain number of characters have been typed.

This is the function that sets the rowSource. I refactored the code so that it can be used on any comboBox in any Form with any Query.

```
Dim inputStub As String

Function ComboLimiter(targetCombo As ComboBox, minChars As Integer, Query As String, searchField As String)
    Dim inputStr As String: inputStr = targetCombo.Text 'Set input string
    Dim newStub As String: newStub = Nz(Left(inputStr, minChars), "") 'Set first n characters of targetCombo.Text

    If newStub <> inputStub Then 'If first n chars are the same as previously, do nothing.
        If Len(newStub) < minChars Then
            'Remove the RowSource
            targetCombo.RowSource = Query & " WHERE (False);"
            inputStub = ""
        Else
            'New RowSource
            targetCombo.RowSource = Query & " WHERE (" & searchField & " Like """ & newStub & "*"") ORDER BY " & searchField & ";"
            inputStub = newStub
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

And the function can be bound to the ComboBox change event like this:

```
Private Sub UPCCombo_Change()
    Call ComboLimiter(Me.UPCCombo, 1, _
    "SELECT ID, UPC_Case, Description FROM itemlist", "UPC_Case")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a known bug where there are sometimes issues with large recordsets like this.  Are you sorting on a text based field?  Try removing the sort if so and seeing if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I've already made a solution, I'm just finishing coding it and then I'll answer my own question